# Disable axios redirects in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I'm currently developing an react-native app that authenticates using a server that returns an 302, and a location redirect in the response header. But I need an variable that inside the location header, and I cannot read them after redirect.
Curl or postman allows me to ignore those redirects, but from what I understood from it, XMLHttpRequest will handle the redirect before returning anything. With that the case, I did try setting maxRedirects: 0 or redirect: 'manual' (See code example)
Is there a way to not get redirected, may it be with another library, or does this require backend changes?

Any help is appreciated.

SilentLucidity

```
const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    auth: {
      username: 'username@example.com,
      password: 'Hello123!',
    },
    maxRedirects: 0,
    redirect: 'manual',
  };
```